# The time evolution of levi-Civita connection

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, connections

Assume a smooth one-parameter family of Riemannian metrics $g_{t}$. Write $h:=\frac {\partial}{\partial t}g$. 
In addition, assume that the Levi-civita connection on the Riemannian manifold $(M,g_{t})$ is given. I'm not sure if my following reasoning is correct.

In local coordinates $(x^i)$, the connection is given by:
$$\nabla_{X}Y=(X^{i}Y^{j}\Gamma^{k}_{ij}+X^{i}\frac{\partial Y^{k}}{\partial x^i})\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}.$$

Since in the same local coordinates the metric $g=g_{kp}dx^{k}dx^{p}$, then we have:

$$g(\nabla_{X}Y,Z)=(g_{kp}dx^{k}dx^{p})((X^{i}Y^{j}\Gamma^{k}_{ij}+X^{i}\frac{\partial Y^{k}}{\partial x^i})\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k},Z^{p}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{p}})=g_{kp}(X^{i}Y^{j}\Gamma^{k}_{ij}+X^{i}\frac{\partial Y^{k}}{\partial x^i})Z^{p}$$

Since, $dx^{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}=\delta_{i}^{j}$.
Then the derivative by $t$ is:
$$\partial_{t}(g(\nabla_{X}Y,Z))=\partial_{t}g_{kp}*(X^{i}Y^{j}\Gamma^{k}_{ij}+X^{i}\frac{\partial Y^{k}}{\partial x^i})Z^{p}+g_{kp}*\partial_t((X^{i}Y^{j}\Gamma^{k}_{ij}+X^{i}\frac{\partial Y^{k}}{\partial x^i})Z^{p})=$$
$$=h(\nabla_{X}Y,Z)+g(\partial_t\nabla_{X}Y,Z).$$
Are my calculations correct, or am I just making lots of mistakes? I would appreciate for any comments/corrections.

Comment: this looks ok to me, assuming you are aware of the fact that it is $\nabla$ (the differential operator) which is time dependent (while $X, Y$ are not). Also, as a side remark, $h$ is usually reserved for the 2nd fundamental form. If you are looking at embedded manifolds you should prefer a different letter, but that's of course up to you.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, for the assurance. Actually, I'm working with Ricci flow and the evolution of various geometric constructions. And $h$ usually denotes the time derivative of the metric tensor. But yes, I should've made myself more clear on the notation.